# how to display collection not in a list

Tags: wpf, data-binding

I would like to display a collection of objects. By using ListBox I can do display them one after another. However I want every one in different position, which would be specified in it's parameters.

```
public class object1
{
//stuff

public double margin_x {get;set;}
public double margin_y {get;set;}
}

//Collection to be displayed:
public ObservableCollection<object1> collection1 {get;set;}
```

How can I do it?

Then, if it's possible, can I display two collections in one panel? For example they would be collection1 of squares and collection2 of lines between them.

Comment: A Layout Control like a grid would do the trick much better.

Comment: Absolutely not. Since I want to set objects position dynamically, grid is pointless.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If anyone'd be interested in future, I've found a solution. To display items wherever I want I used ListView with Canvas as ItemsPanel. To display two kinds of objects, I make two ListViews with transparent background:

```
<ListView ItemsSource="{Binding collection1}">
        <ListView.ItemsPanel>
            <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                <Canvas />
            </ItemsPanelTemplate>
        </ListView.ItemsPanel>
        <ListView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <Rectangle Margin="{Binding mar}" Width="30" Height="30" Stroke="Black" />
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListView.ItemTemplate>
</ListView>

<ListView ItemsSource="{Binding collection2}">
        <ListView.ItemsPanel>
            <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                <Canvas />
            </ItemsPanelTemplate>
        </ListView.ItemsPanel>
        <ListView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <Line X1="{Binding x1}" X2="{Binding x2}" Y1="{Binding y1}" Y2="{Binding y2}" Stroke="Black" />
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListView.ItemTemplate>
    </ListView>
```

And in codebehind:

```
public class object1
{
private double x0;
private double y0;

public Thickness mar { get { return new Thickness(x0,y0,0,0); } }
}
public class object2
{
    public x1 {get;set;}
    public x2 {get;set;}
    public y1 {get;set;}
    public y2 {get;set;}
}
public ObservableCollection<object1> collection1 {get;set;}
public ObservableCollection<object2> colletcion2 {get;set;}
```